Limiting distribution of the Wishart process
Consider the Wishart process:
$$
dS_t = \sqrt{S_t} \, dB_t Q + Q^\top \, dB^\top_t \sqrt{S_t} + (S_t K + K^\top S_t + \Omega \Omega^\top) \, dt
$$
Or the restricted version where $\Omega = \sqrt{\alpha} Q^\top$
According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3256.pdf, which uses the restricted version, if $\alpha \ge p+1$ where $p$ is the dimension of $S_t$, then the process has a unique solution and $S_t$ is p.s.d for all $t$. It also claims that the limiting distribution is the noncentral Wishart distribution.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10287-021-00388-7 gives us the mean of the limiting distribution, $S_{\infty}$ as satisfying the Sylvester equation:
$$-\Omega \Omega^\top = K^\top S_{\infty} + S_{\infty} K$$
(It makes the drift term 0 so this seems reasonable).
Is there, similarly simple way to relate the parameters of that limiting distribution to the parameters of the process?
